# Possible Conference Speaking Sponsorships -- 2011

Tags: discussion, conferences

We're evaluating the feasibility of **sponsoring a member of the programmers community to speak at a conference in 2011**.

Speaking is a relatively big "ask", so this needs to be planned many months in advance. Let's get started!

We'd like the community to establish **where** ...

> What relevant programming conferences are coming up in 2011 that have open speaker slots or calls for papers?

... and then **who**.

> Which members of the community are strongly interested in being sponsored by Stack Exchange, Inc to speak at one of the above conferences in 2011?

To be clear, the speaker is free talk about anything he or she wants so long as it would be roughly on topic for this site -- with a quick acknowledgement of support from Stack Exchange and a mention of the community here.

Comment: The topic is quite important...

Comment: Hmm... could be fun.

Comment: About what? The site, some speaker determined topic, or an SE or conference determined one?

Answer (score 5):

For the **who**

### [Anna Lear](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/226/anna-lear)

My second choice is [Chris F](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/47/chrisf), if someone put an answer with him, I'll upvote it.

I have no idea where.

Comment: Thanks, Pierre. :) I'm theoretically open to the idea.

Answer (score 4):

What about Pierre 303? He's a stalwart representative and is certainly prolific on the site.

Answer (score 3):

One conference that comes to mind is [Software Craftsmanship North America](http://scna.softwarecraftsmanship.org/). I'm not sure if it's still accepting speakers for 2011, although the [Speakers page](http://scna.softwarecraftsmanship.org/speakers/) seems to suggest so at the time of this writing.

I second @Michael's question. What sort of talks are you envisioning here?

Comment: You include something about being a moderator.

Answer (score 3):

I would absolutely **hate** standing up in front of an audience speaking about anything.

While I'm happy to spout forth on the internet and in the office, doing it in lecture hall fills me with dread.

Sorry to disappoint Anna and Pierre.

Comment: That's more than fair enough. I will delete my answer.

Comment: this is also why, as in moderator elections, we always prefer a *self-nomination* .. third party nominations have too many moving parts.

Comment: @Jeff - I didn't mind the "nomination" (in one sense it's quite flattering), but as for anything else the nominee *has* to agree.

Comment: This could be a great way to overcome your fear of public speaking.  Lots of people here believe you have something to say that would greatly benefit the community ;)

Comment: Agreed. @ChrisF loves being a moderator.

Answer (score 1):

I nominate...me.

Because I'm not shy, and like to talk.

Sometimes it's even interesting.

And I'd be happy to wear my stackoverflow t-shirt; I look good in black!

If it helps, I signed the [software craftsmanship manifesto](http://manifesto.softwarecraftsmanship.org/) years ago ;-)

Comment: As a sample topic, I think I can come up with a good analogy between woodworking and software craftsmanship, and possibly even create a tiny Jon Skeet out of oak and ash as part of the presentation.

Comment: riding a unicorn...

Comment: brandishing a waffle...